# clear type bug when animating something with transparent background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I,m making text slider using jquery (text scrols using transitions provided by easing jquery plugin). The parent DIV has some image as a background.

Everything works fine in every browser, but not in IE 6,7,8. Strange distortions occur in IE when text and the IMG's are being animated.

I learned recently that is fault of IE clear-type filter. I,ve googled about it and the only solution I found was to set background-color to what is being animated. But I want the background to be transparent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem frequently. Unfortunately, I've not found a solution short of:

```
jQuery.fx.off = ($.browser.msie ) ? true : false;
// Do your fading/animating/transitions
jQuery.fx.off = false;
```

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news!